Save changes in webview 2 through a button in Win Forms
I'm working on an application tool in Win Forms that my company uses to see all workitems that exist in queries in azure dev. For example when you press on a query you get redirected with the help of webview2 to that exact workitem in azure dev. You can already in the tool write and save tags that pops up on the website through a button. But if I try make other changes like adding a description for a workitem and then press the save button it dosen't work.
I know that you can save changes directly on the website but my supervisors wanted it to be so you only has to press the save button existing in the tool, rather than doing the process twice. Here is the button code for saving tags in case anyone is curious
private void button_sign_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     if (textBoxTag.Text != "")
     {
         int id = currentworkitemID;
         wis.publish(textBoxTag.Text, id, textchanged);
         textchanged = false;
         changed.Clear();
         refreshGraph();
     }
     else MessageBox.Show("TAG CANNOT BE EMPTY");
 }     

I did get the feeling while searching for answers that it seems unlikely for this thing to work but I thought if you already are able to save tags on the website you can save other things as well. If anyone knows something I would be very happy for the help.
Edit: publish field
  public void publish(string tag, int id, bool change)
   {

       foreach (WorkItem wi in CacheItems.Values)
       {
           if (wi.IsDirty || wi.Id == id)
           {
               if (wi.IsValid())
               {
                   wi.Fields["Tags"].Value = wi.Fields["Tags"].Value.ToString() + "; " + tag;
                   try
                   {
                       wi.Save();
                       if (wi.Fields.Contains("Microsoft.VSTS.Common.Triage"))
                       {
                           if (isTriaged(wi.Id) && wi.Fields["Microsoft.VSTS.Common.Triage"].Value.ToString() != "Triaged")
                           {
                               Triaged.Remove(wi.Id);
                               Decided.Add(wi.Id);
                               goesToDecided(wi.Id);
                           }
                           else
                           if ((!isTriaged(wi.Id)) && wi.Fields["Microsoft.VSTS.Common.Triage"].Value.ToString() == "Triaged")
                           {
                               Triaged.Add(wi.Id);
                               Decided.Remove(wi.Id);
                               goesToTriaged(wi.Id);
                           }

                       }
                       Changed.Add(wi.Id);
                   }
                   catch (System.Exception ex)
                   {
                       MessageBox.Show(ex.Message + "\n\nRedo updates in WI" + wi.Id.ToString() + "!", "Save Failed: ");
                       wi.SyncToLatest();
                   }

               }
               else
               {
                   MessageBox.Show("WorkItem: " + wi.Id.ToString() + " not valid ");
               }
           }
       }


From the C# code you posted, I noticed the line below.
wis.publish(textBoxTag.Text, id, textchanged);

This line seems is calling the customized method 'publish' to update tags on the specified work item.
You can try to reference the code of this customized method to check what APIs/methods/properties are used in this method to update the tags field on the specified work item.
Then you can try to rewrite the customized method (or define a new method) to update other fields on the specified work item. To update comments, you can try to use the comments related APIs/methods/properties in the method.

Do you have any suggestions of how a can do that? Because I don't really know how to proceed.

@JonatanPräst, Since you did not post the actual code of the 'publish' method, I am not sure how it works. It might call the "Work Items - REST API" or the corresponding .NET client libraries. To update other fields, you also can try to use the corresponding APIs.

Added the method now
